# How do I make a moving platform that only activates after the player is on it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was actually able to make the moving platform activate after the player was on it, but if I jumped while still on the platform, the platform would stop moving, because "isOnPlatform = false". This looks weird. I want the platform to activate when the player is on it and keep moving until it comes to the second waypoint, where it waits and can be activated again if the player decides to go back.

```
public class WaypointFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] waypoints;
    private int currentWaypointIndex = 0;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 2f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].transform.position, transform.position) < .1f){
            currentWaypointIndex++;
            if (currentWaypointIndex >= waypoints.Length){
                currentWaypointIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: So. Adjust the code accordingly. Somewhere you have isonplatform. Which sounds like the player controls the platform. How about the platform controls itself. It finds the player upon it and moves  but only stops at the end when a player is no longer on it

Answer (score 0):

You can check when the player is on the platform
with `OnCollisionEnter` if the platform has a collider.
And with `OnCollisonExit` when the player exits.
If its 2D use than `OnCollisionEnter2D` or `OnCollisionExit2D`

```
public class WaypointFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] waypoints;
    private int currentWaypointIndex = 0;
    private bool movePlatform = false;
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 2f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (movePlatform)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].transform.position, transform.position) < .1f)
            {
                currentWaypointIndex++;
                if (currentWaypointIndex >= waypoints.Length)
                {
                    currentWaypointIndex = 0;
                    
                }
                movePlatform = false;
            }
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            movePlatform = true;
        }
    }
}
    }
```